# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line

Tags: android

Тестирую приложение на АПИ 21 - работает без ошибок, пробую запустить на апи 16, вылетает такой стектрейс:

```
    10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #75: Error inflating class com.widget.base.ProductNDIndicator
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.lavkalavka.pages.catalog.productview.ProductGridAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(ProductGridAdapter.java:32)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.lavkalavka.pages.catalog.productview.ProductGridAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(ProductGridAdapter.java:16)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5223)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4449)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4359)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1961)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(GridLayoutManager.java:438)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1333)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:562)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(GridLayoutManager.java:171)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2900)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3071)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:948)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1043)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1866)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1687)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
10-20 18:40:42.822 1522-1522/com.market.lavkalavka E/AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$Travers
```

Разметка на которой вылетает ошибка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/product_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/main">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/holder"
            android:background="@color/main">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="160dp"
                android:id="@+id/productImage" />
            <com.widget.lavkaviews.text.Text
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/productTitle"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:minLines="2"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/productImage"
                android:text="Яблоки от Валерия Жомера"
                android:textColor="#262626"
                android:maxLines="2" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50px"
                android:layout_height="50px"
                android:id="@+id/imageSas"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/productImage"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/productImage" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/pricePortionHolder"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/productTitle">

                <com.widget.lavkaviews.text.Text
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/productPrice"
                    android:text="570 Р"
                    android:textColor="#262626"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/roubleSymbol"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/productPrice"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/productPrice"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/productPrice" />

                <com.widget.lavkaviews.text.Text
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/portionText"
                    android:text="/ 1 кг"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/roubleSymbol" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/ndframe"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/productImage"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/productImage">
                <com.widget.base.ProductNDIndicator
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/nd_indicator"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="1px"
                android:layout_height="1px"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/productImage"
                android:id="@+id/pivot"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Класс, который якобы нельзя инфлейтить

```
public class ProductNDIndicator extends RelativeLayout {

    private static final int SHADOW_RANGE = 8;

    Text month;
    Text day_of_month;
    Text day_of_week;
    Text nd;

    float cx;
    float cy;

    public ProductNDIndicator(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.widget_product_nd, this);

        setTexts();
        setBackground(backround());

        this.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

        cx = this.getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
        cy = this.getMeasuredHeight() / 2;
        setPivotX(cx);
        setPivotY(cy);
        setRotation(-35);
    }

    public void waiting(Product product) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(product.getSupplyDate());
        month.setText(Time.getMonthName(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)));
        day_of_month.setText(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH + "");
        day_of_week.setText(Time.getDayOfWeek(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)));
        nd.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
    }

    public void nd() {
        month.setVisibility(GONE);
        day_of_week.setVisibility(GONE);
        day_of_month.setVisibility(GONE);
        nd.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        nd.setText("нет в наличии".toUpperCase());
    }

    private GradientDrawable backround() {
        GradientDrawable g = new GradientDrawable(
                GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM,
                new int[] {
                        Decorator.WHITE_TRANSPARENT_100,
                        Decorator.WHITE_TRANSPARENT_80,
                        Decorator.WHITE_TRANSPARENT_80,
                        Decorator.WHITE_TRANSPARENT_100
                }
        );
        g.setGradientType(GradientDrawable.LINEAR_GRADIENT);
        g.setSize((int)(cx * 1.5), (int)cy);
        g.setGradientCenter(cx, cy);
        return g;
    }

    private void setTexts() {
        day_of_month = (Text) findViewById(R.id.day_of_month);
        day_of_month.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, Decorator.getHeightBasedOnIPhone960(76));
        day_of_month.setTextColor(Decorator.LAVKA_RED);
        day_of_month.setTypeface(font.font133sb.typeface());
        day_of_month.setShadowLayer(
                Decorator.getHeightBasedOnIPhone960(SHADOW_RANGE),
                0,
                0,
                Decorator.WHITE_TRANSPARENT_80
        );

        month = (Text) findViewById(R.id.month);
        month.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, Decorator.getHeightBasedOnIPhone960(34));
        month.setTextColor(Decorator.ND_PROD_MONTH);
        month.setShadowLayer(
                Decorator.getHeightBasedOnIPhone960(SHADOW_RANGE),
                0,
                0,
                Decorator.WHITE_TRANSPARENT_80
        );

        day_of_week = (Text) findViewById(R.id.day_of_week);
        day_of_week.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, Decorator.getHeightBasedOnIPhone960(26));
        day_of_week.setTextColor(Decorator.ND_PROD_WEEK_DAY);
        day_of_week.setShadowLayer(
                Decorator.getHeightBasedOnIPhone960(SHADOW_RANGE),
                0,
                0,
                Decorator.WHITE_TRANSPARENT_80
        );

        nd = (Text) findViewById(R.id.nd_text);
        nd.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, Decorator.getHeightBasedOnIPhone960(28));
        nd.setTextColor(Decorator.LAVKA_RED);
        nd.setShadowLayer(
                Decorator.getHeightBasedOnIPhone960(SHADOW_RANGE),
                0,
                0,
                Decorator.WHITE_TRANSPARENT_80
        );
    }
}
```

Немного запутанно, но вкратце `getHeightBasedOnIPhone960` возвращает интеджер, осноанный на макетах, нарисованных дизайнером. Этой функции передается число пикселей в высоту с макета сделанного на основе айфона, он ввозвращает пропорциональное значениие для экрана андроид. Сейчас вопрос этого не касается, так что прошу не судить разработчика за особую изощренность )) `Text` это TextView с нужным тайпфейсом и ещё парой нужных мне функций, `NestedGridLayoutManager` переопределенный `LayoutManager`, который считает высоту для `RecyclerView` (так как потребовалось поместить его в `ScrollView`). Пытался искать решение, но везде пишут, что такая ошибка чаще всего вызвана попыткой прописать класс в разметке без имени пакета, но у меня с этим все нормально.

`Inflate` происходит в onCreateViewHolder в адаптере для `RecyclerView`.

```
    @Override
    public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_product_in_grid_new, parent, false);
//        return new ViewHolder(view);
        return new ProductViewHolder(view);
    }
```

пробовал делать `inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_product_in_grid_new, parent, false);` и `inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_product_in_grid_new, null);` , результат один. Есть идеи, почему может вылетать такая ошибка?

Comment: Попробуйте локализировать проблему в классе `ProductNDIndicator`. Например убирая части кода и пробуя запускать без них.

Answer (score 1):

Установите `targetSdkVersion` и `compileSdkVersion` в 16 и среда разработки должна почеркнуть неподдерживаемые в данном АПИ элементы.

Также попробуйте добавить остальные конструкторы, в частности с третим параметром `int defStyle`.

Comment: Ну как бы насчёт апи даже не совет, сделано очень давно и внимательно контролируется. А вот с конструкторами попробую, хотя я успеваю увидеть другие свои кастомные вью, прежде, чем перехожу на страницу, которая выдаёт ошибку

Comment: @iamthevoid если есть возможность - выложите ссылочку на минимальный пример в котором воспроизводится проблема.

Comment: Я сделал здесь такую экстракцию. Почему то более подробно стектрейс не хочет акцентироваться на строке, ссылается на разметку, хотя там может быть куда более глубинная вещь. Чуть позже дотянусь до компьютера и буду пробовать следовать советам

Comment: @iamthevoid я имел в виду выложить приложение на гитхаб или в zip архиве чтобы другие поллзователи могли поклацать приложение и увидеть проблему  своими глазами.

Comment: Не могу, к сожалению.

Comment: нет, дело не в конструкторах, я в конструкторе с дефстайлом по идее должен ввызвать this(context, attributeSet), верно?

Comment: Вероятно да, иначе оно и на 21 апи не работало. Еще можно попытаться протестить на симуляторах с 17, 18 и 19 чтобы точно определить минимальный апи на котором работает и посмотреть что там было нового.

Comment: this.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED); вызывает ошибку, странно

Comment: Возможно это как-то связанно с этим багом - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63673

Comment: Переписал onMeasure. Решил.